# Mysql : select id that have multiple value

Tags: mysql, select

i have table1 :

```
+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+------+---------+
| 1    | name1   |
| 2    | name2   |
| 3    | name3   |
| 4    | name4   |
+------+---------+
```

i have table2 :

```
+------+---------+
| id   | object  |
+------+---------+
| 1    |    4    |
| 1    |    8    |
| 2    |    23   |
| 2    |    8    |
| 2    |    9    |
| 3    |    2    |
| 3    |    8    |
| 4    |    9    |
| 4    |    23   |
+------+---------+
```

i want to select name = name2, that have object 8,23 , but ignore the other id that have just objet 8 or just object 23, the result will be :

```
+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+------+---------+
| 2    | name2   |
+------+---------+
```

thanks for help, master.

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far? Do you understand how `COUNT()` aggregates and `GROUP BY` work?

Comment: At the very least, consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET - as well as your best effort(s) to date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SELF JOIN` when you want to find one `id` has two different values.

Could you try this? You can test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a10879/1/0

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT a.id
    FROM table2 AS a INNER JOIN table2 AS b
      ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE a.object = 8 AND b.object = 23
) x INNER JOIN table1 ON x.id = table1.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select a.id, a.name
from table1 a
where exists (select 1 from table2 c
              where object = 8 and c.id = a.id)
and exists (select 1 from table2 c
            where object = 23  and c.id = a.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id, table1.name FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.name = "name2" AND
table1.id = table2.id and (table2.object = 8 OR table2.object = 23);
```